# LLBLGen Template Binding test for date type

Tags: c#, llblgenpro, llblgen

In the LLBLGen Template Bindings Viewer, I want to check if a field is a date type, and if so, do an action

I have similar, that checks for a string type:

```
<[Foreach EntityField]> 
<[If IsStringField]><[EntityFieldName]> = ""; <[EndIf]>
<[NextForeach]>
```

I'd like to be able to do something similar for date types,  like:

```
<[Foreach EntityField]> 
<[If IsDateField]><[EntityFieldName]> = DateTime.Today; <[EndIf]>
<[NextForeach]>
```

however, IsDateField is not available as a command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I no longer have this question.  Does it need cancelling or something?

Comment: Did you come up with an answer?  If so, you can answer your own question.  If not, you can request to delete the question and then flag it for moderator attention